# Three.js Buffer Management

Tags: javascript, three.js, webgl

i am trying to improve my webgl skills and thought the best way to learn is by looking at three.js [Three.js](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/). I understand how to create and bind buffers, shaders etc.But what am i looking for is how does three.js manage the process of binding buffers for example

```
gl.createBuffer
gl.bindBuffer
gl.bufferData
```

Can someone explain how Three.js does work under the hood?

Comment: Three.js use to create most things inside [WebGLRenderer.js](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/dev/src/renderers/WebGLRenderer.js). You build all your data (geometry, materials, mesh, scene, lights) and three.js looks at that and creates the buffers, shaders, etc.. You can search for [`createBuffer`](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=createBuffer) to find the places buffers are created. Search for `bindBuffer` and/or `bufferData` as well.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This answer is applicable to Three.js r84.

Three.js uses 3 types of geometries :

- [`Geometry`](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/dev/src/core/Geometry.js)
- [`BufferGeometry`](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/dev/src/core/BufferGeometry.js)
- ([`DirectGeometry`](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/dev/src/core/DirectGeometry.js))

`Geometry` stores the geometry parameters (vertices, normals, colors, ...) in a user-friendly way.
`BufferGeometry` stores the geometry in [`BufferAttribute`](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/dev/src/core/BufferAttribute.js), which are simply wrappers for buffers (or [*typed arrays*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Typed_arrays)) which contains the data you typically send with `gl.bufferData()`.
(`DirectGeometry` is only used to convert from `Geometry` to `BufferGeometry`.)

Basically, the common Three.js renderer, [`WebGLRenderer`](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/dev/src/renderers/WebGLRenderer.js), deals with `BufferGeometry` whereas the user deals with `Geometry`.

But, as long as you don't render the scene, no geometry conversion is done and nothing is sent to the GPU. (No buffer created.)

To prevent the engine from polluting the user-space with WebGL-specific stuff like buffers, Three.js implements some sort of wrappers that are included into the renderer. Two of these wrappers are :

- [`WebGLGeometries`](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/dev/src/renderers/webgl/WebGLGeometries.js) which stores all the `BufferGeometry`s ;
- [`WebGLAttributes`](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/dev/src/renderers/webgl/WebGLAttributes.js) which stores all the WebGL buffers.

The mapping between user objects and objects inside those wrappers is done through the `uuid` property.

When a render is requested, the renderer browse all of the objects of the scene. If an object `uuid` is not present inside one of the wrappers, some processing is done and the transformed object is stored.

That's where things get interesting, because that's where an object's `Geometry` is converted to a `BufferGeometry` inside the `WebGLGeometries` wrapper and a `BufferGeometry` is converted to one or more `WebGLBuffer` inside the `WebGLAttributes` wrapper using the functions you listed :

```
gl.createBuffer();
gl.bindBuffer();
gl.bufferData();
```

Check this [file](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/dev/src/renderers/webgl/WebGLAttributes.js) to find the actual calls.

Also, when an object like a `Geometry` is updated, its `version` counter is incremented so that it does not match the `version` written in the wrappers anymore. The renderer then knows it should update the wrapped object.

Finally, when an object gets added to a wrapper, a listener is attached to it so that the renderer gets notified when an object is removed and can thus dispose the wrapped object.